# QtCreator: Custom QML Import Path states that the directory I specified is not a directory. The QML Type I am trying to import turns green

Tags: qt, qml

I hope the question is phrased properly, for I do not understand full what is happening in my application. I am currently trying to implement a custom version of [QGroundControl](http://qgroundcontrol.com/) and one of the things I am trying to do is replace the virtual joystick with a slider to control the yaw and pitch independently of a combined joystick via sliders.

I have created a custom qml file named "CustomHorizontalSlider.qml" and have placed it in this first image and have made sure that the file path is correct in Visual Studio Code: QtCreator Path:
[image: QtCreator Path]

I also have added the file to the custom.qrc and craeted a qmldir. Along with that I have used the updateqrc.py to make sure that the custom files are up to date: custom.qrc:
[image: custom.qrc]

This is the error that I get when attempting to use that qml file now. Alongside here is the code if it is relevant: Error Message:
[image: Error Message] Import at the top:
[image: Import at the top] Code changed to green:
[image: Code changed to green]

Lastly, when I attempt to remove the import the module is no longer green.

Answer (score 0):

Try importing as follows

```
import [path_to_dir] as MyControl
```

Example:

```
import "../../controls" as MyControl
```

And then you can use the alias to define elements (MyControl.[Name])

Example

```
MyControl.MyCustomButton
{
...
}
```